# Change button function on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, django-templates

Not sure what/where I went wrong.  Have been trying to dynamically change button function on click.  One is to open Bootstrap Modal and another is to go act as submit.  For some reason the if statement did not get executed at all.  Though I am totally new to jQuery and have been searching around with no luck. Appreciate any pointer please.  Here is what I have

```
submitButton.click(function(){
// submitButton.on('click', function() { 
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlAct"), // get value of select option drop down list
        choosenAct = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  

    alert("hello"); // to check that this function gets call when  click the button
    alert(choosenAct); // check the value
    if (choosenAct == 'markasgone') {
        alert(choosenAct)
        $('#reasonModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        alert(choosenAct); // add the missing 'n' that cause issue in if stmt
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Result of the above script is :

I get 2 alerts before the if statement and non afterwords. I put another alert in the if stmt as I was suspecting that the **if stmt did not get executed.**  This seems to be the case since I only get 2 alerts.  What do I miss?

What I want to achieve is if a user select 'markasgone' option then when click on the GO button in a form, it will pop up a Bootstrap Modal asking for reasons otherwise just submit the form.

Please help.  Thanks a ton in advanced.

UPDATE: Thanks to Sergey for spotting the typo.  The problem I now have is the BootStrap Modal window is not shown.  The code I have is

```
<button id="gobutton">Go</button>  

{% comment %}**** Modal ****{% endcomment %}
<div class="modal fade" id="reasonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reasonModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header"> <h4>Reason Please</h4> </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p> Please let us know your reasons: </p>
            {% include "common/reasons.html" %}
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
         </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in `alert(chooseAct);`, the one under `else`:  `chooseAct` is misspelled and causes an error. You can probably see that in debugger console too if you open it.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, changing correcting the typo now execute the if stmt.  Wow..staring at it for hours and did not see it.   Now that the if stmt is sure executed, I did not manage to get the modal form to pop up.  Is that the right way to call a Bootstrap Modal form in jQuery.

Comment: All works now.  So it was another typo mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:  Missing the n at line 11

```
submitButton.click(function(){
// submitButton.on('click', function() { 
var e = document.getElementById("ddlAct"), // get value of select option drop down list
    choosenAct = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  

alert("hello"); // to check that this function gets call when  click the button
alert(choosenAct); // check the value
if (choosenAct == 'markasgone') {
    alert(choosenAct)
    $('#reasonModal').modal('show');
} else {
    alert(choosenAct);
    $("form").submit();
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  The if stmt now gets executed.  But I get a new problem!  The bootstrap modal is not shown.   Any help please. Thanks

Comment: FYI - the bootstrap model works now.  It was another typo in my code.  Thank you